# How to extract specific file from zip archive

Tags: windows, batch, zip

i have a folder containing all zip files and i want to use the batch to search through all zip using 7zip and extract the specific file name posted below.

how do i use this batch using 7zip
this code below runs but not extracting

```
FOR %%F IN ("C:\Users\sarah\Downloads\MAME\FBA_Arcade_Latest\*.zip") DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\" *5.bin -r -y
```

i want to extract to **C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)**


**string 5.bin**

Comment: It is not clear what your question is, please take a minute, to make specify what your question is.  You should also take an additional minute to properly format your question.

Comment: please check post now

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
FOR %%F IN ("C:\Users\sarah\Downloads\MAME\FBA_Arcade_Latest\*.zip") DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x %%~fF "-oC:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\" *5.bin -r -y
```

Comment: try changing to `"-oC:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\* "` to get archive name to prefix the filename.